# XSLT multiple nodes identity

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSLT. I read that you can check a node's identity like this: `generate-id(.) == generate-id($someNode)`.  If true both nodes are identical. Is there also a simple way to compare a set of nodes to be identical: $set1 == $set2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
count($set1) = count($set2) and count($set1|$set2) = count($set1)
```

Comment: This works fine. Can you explain the logic of this operation? Thank you!

Comment: If the second condition is true (the union of two sets is the same size as the first set), then the second set must be a subset of the first. If the first condition is also true (the two sets are the same size) then the second set must be the same as the first, because the only subset of A that has the same size as A is A itself. (If you want a more rigorous proof, you'll have to ask a mathematician...)

Comment: No need to ask a mathematician. This makes perfectly sense.